# Ansible - Reading output of remote scripts into variable for processing by another play

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm writing a playbook that will run a script on a number of remote boxes. The stdout_lines of running these remotes needs to be collated into one single array that can be passed to another play in the book that is run locally, where this big collated array is then passed to a module.

I can't seem to find a way to do this. Some code kind-of stuff (that doesn't work) is below:

```
---

- name: Gather information from hosts
  hosts: remote-hosts
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  vars:
    information: |
      {%- set o=[] %}
      {%- for i in play_hosts %}
        {%- for line in hostvars[i].info_script_output_lines %}
          {%- if o.append(hostvars[i].info_script_output_lines[line]) %}
          {%- endif %}
        {%- endfor %}
      {%- endfor %}
      {{ o }}

  tasks:
    - name: Run info retrieval script
      script: /script_folder/script_that_outputs_lines.sh
      register: info_script_output

    - set_fact:
        info_script_output_lines: "{{ info_script_output.stdout_lines }}"

    - set_fact:
        final_info: "{{ info_script_output_lines }}"
        run_once: true
        delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
        delegate_facts: true

- name: Output result
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Output = {{ hostvars['localhost']['final_info'] }}
```

`hostvars['localhost']['final_info']` doesn't exist in the second play.

Can anyone explain whether I'm (a) constructing my array correctly with the output facts from each remote and (b) how to get that final consolidated array into another play so I can use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
---
- hosts: mygroup
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - shell: echo begin; echo {{ inventory_hostname }}; echo end;
      register: cmd_output
    - set_fact:
        my_lines: "{{ cmd_output.stdout_lines }}"

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    combined_lines: "{{ groups['mygroup'] | map('extract',hostvars,'my_lines') | sum(start=[]) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ combined_lines }}"
```

Use [`extract`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers) filter and then `sum(start=[])` to flatten the list into long list of lines.

Comment: When the returned command is expected to return a single line, it can be easily accessed by `{{ cmd_output.stdout_lines[0] }}`.